# How to use input$tabs to reference the output name in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

the below works

```
library(shiny)   

ui <- (basicPage( 

 tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
          tabPanel("Tab A", value = "A",
                   "This is Tab A content",
                   textOutput("tabA")),
          tabPanel("Tab B", value = "B",
                   "Here's some content for tab B.",
                   textOutput("tabB")))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tabA <- renderText({paste0("You are viewing tab ", input$tabs)})
  output$tabB <- renderText({paste0("You are viewing tab ", input$tabs)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to select the name of the output depending on which tab is selected.

```
output[["tabA"]] <- renderText({paste0("You are viewing tab ", input$tabs)})
```

the above is fine but the below does't work since it wants a reactive context.

```
 output[[paste0("tab", input$tabs)]] <- renderText({paste0("You are viewing tab ", input$tabs)})
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: using a generic name for the output and putting it outside the tabsetPanel also works. i.e. only one textOutput("tabX")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(shiny)   

ui <- (basicPage( 
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Tab A", value = "A","This is Tab A content",textOutput("tabA")),
              tabPanel("Tab B", value = "B","Here's some content for tab B.",textOutput("tabB")))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    output[[paste0("tab", input$tabs)]] <- renderText({paste0("You are viewing tab ", input$tabs)})
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```